# Packer images vs Vagrant images

Tags: packer

Mitchell Hashimoto said somewhere that vagrant should be not used in production. As I understand packer.io is exactly filling that gap - one can build EC2/Rackspace/.. images. What are the underyling differences in terms of virtualization? Both are VM's, but they must be different type of VM's. How does an AWS prebuild image different from a Virtualbox image or VMWare image? Any general hints at the underlying technologies would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer can be used to create vagrant boxes or production boxes.

"don't use vagrant in production" : vagrant boxes are built with security holes in it to allow smooth scripting/ssh/tunnelling/sudo (no passphrase, known password : vagrant).

It can be seen as kind of replacement for [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee)

Production can be on

- your "laptop" (virtualbox)
- own datacenter or your client datacenter (vmware)
- in hosting service like (digital ocean/rackspace/...)
- more specific hosting like AWS

AWS prebuild image (AMI) helps a lot when using "auto scaling". When aws want to start a new server it starts with ready to start (no provisioning/deployment script at startup)
See this [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/ndemoor/phoenix-servers-with-packer) on how packer can fit with aws.

Answer (score 0):

update: as far as I know the "security holes" are no more there so vagrant can absolutely be used to create production boxes.

Of course it's a production environment and so it requires some fine tuning of the services, but this is normal and has nothing to do with vagrant.

Comment: generally, it seems like we could just assume that if the project founder says it's not meant for production use, then he's in a well qualified position for giving us that advice.